# How should I initialize this variable for use with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'd like to do is make a variable that is a specific class/id object.
For example, on lines (5) and (8) where I do a literal reference of the ID, shoe-carousel, I want to have a variable that represents shoe-carousel instead.
The problem is that if I do something like:

```
var fooCarousel = $('.shoe-carousel');
```

it'll work for line (5), not for line (8)

```
1. //initialize the slide in focus and what will be the center slide
2. var slideInFocus = document.createElement('img');
​3. 
4. //set the index of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
5. slideInFocus.index = $('.shoe-carousel').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
6.     
7. //set the source of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
8. slideInFocus.src = $('.shoe-carousel .slick-current img').prop('src');
```

To me, it seems like the issue with line 8 is that the single-quotes (') being pushed in from the variable definition are ruining it; so, what's the trick to give to a new JS/jQuery guy like me? Thanks!

Comment: What is ultimate purpose of this code? I doubt it is going to do whatever it is you are trying to do but it's not clear what that would be

Comment: @charlietfl: Well that's encouraging lol :] This code fetches the slickCurrentSlide and propagates to it a larger view screen.

Comment: Not at all sure what that means....or how the rest of this is being used. Also not sure why you create a new image element

Comment: Why does it matter? And why did you "doubt it is going to do whatever it is you are trying to do"? You have no clue what I'm trying to do, yet you're doubting it'll work; that seems like a pretty asinine thing to say, man.

Comment: don't take it personal. The code shown doesn't make sense by itself. You are the one asking for help but without more context it's hard to help. A proper question should state what the intention of the code is, expected behavior and deviation from that expected behavior. Broken code is not a good substitute for proper explanations

Comment: I specifically asked how to get the variable to work. I gave two examples where I'm using said variable, I wrote why I think it's not working, and I gave the variable initialization that I was using that wasn't working for me. Two other people here seemed to know what I was asking w/out me having to waste their time making them read what the intent of my code was when it is irrelevant for this specific question.

Comment: I appreciate your concern, thanks though!

Comment: What is highly unorthodox is creating an image element for this. I assumed that was part of the question / problem. Asking for clarification is the proper thing to do when things don't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first realizing I posted a not-appropriate answer, then reading comments under @Redmega's answer, I think that the most efficience response to the OP's issue is like this:

```
var fooCarousel = $('.shoe-carousel');
1. //initialize the slide in focus and what will be the center slide
2. var slideInFocus = document.createElement('img');
​3. 
4. //set the index of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
5. slideInFocus.index = fooCarousel.slick('slickCurrentSlide');
6.     
7. //set the source of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
8. slideInFocus.src = $('.slick-current img', fooCarousel).prop('src');
```

While very close to the `$fooCarousel.find('.slick-current img')` solution, this way has probably the less performance impact.

Edit: actually it doesn't make any difference, as pointed by @Redmega.

Comment: There is no performance difference. Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" ). [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

Comment: @Redmega Thanks for the link, it removes any incertainty. So my guess was wrong: it's not my day. Sigh :)

Comment: Redmega, that was really awesome of you to make those edits. Thanks to both of you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem doing it the way you are suggesting, the issue is I think your implementation in line 8. How are you trying to call it? Something like this would work well. `.find()` will find the selector within the jquery object you are calling it from.

```
1. var $fooCarousel = $('.shoe-carousel');
2. var slideInFocus = document.createElement('img');
​3. 
4. //set the index of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
5. slideInFocus.index = $fooCarousel.slick('slickCurrentSlide');
6.     
7. //set the source of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
8. slideInFocus.src = $fooCarousel.find('.slick-current img').prop('src');
```

Comment: using `find()` might be a bit more efficient but isn't doing anything different than what OP currently has

Comment: @charlietfl OP's question states `I want to have a variable that represents shoe-carousel instead.` So I showed him how to do that. My guess is he was attempting to concatenate the jquery variable with another string like cFreed did.

Comment: I tend to prefix jQuery element variables with a "$" for readability too!

Comment: @psilocybin That's a very good practice, it helps remind the programmer of the data type of the variable as well, so they don't confuse it with a string.

Answer (score 0):

***Warning**: as pointed by others, this answer doesn't solve the OP issue. I too quickly read the question, so the proposed code below would works only with `fooCarousel` containing the string id!*

Yes it's what you guessed.
And it's easy to workaround, using usual concatenation, like this:

```
1. //initialize the slide in focus and what will be the center slide
2. var slideInFocus = document.createElement('img');
​3. 
4. //set the index of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
5. slideInFocus.index = fooCarousel.slick('slickCurrentSlide');
6.     
7. //set the source of the immediate slide in focus when the page loads
8. slideInFocus.src = $(fooCarousel + ' .slick-current img').prop('src');
```

Comment: `fooCarousel ` is a jQuery object. You can't concatenate object and string

Comment: This does not work, and replicates the issue OP is facing.

Comment: @charlietfl Oh! Sure, my bad. Sorry to have read too quickly.